# Files uploading status in perl Net::FTP module

Tags: perl

I am uploading files from local to FTP using perl Net::FTP Module. After uploading the file, how can I get the status in a scalar variable that the file has been uploaded successfully or not? I am using the code that mentioned below.

```
use strict;
use Net::FTP;


my $ftp_connection=Net::Ftp->new('debian1.com');
$ftp_connection->login("myuser","password");
$ftp_connection->put('D:/to_upload/tested.xml','/root/received/tested.xml');
$ftp_connection->quit;
```

Please provide your valuable suggestions to implement the above task.
Is it possible to transfer the file as binary mode?

Note: I am developing this in Windows OS.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$ftp_connection->put('D:/to_upload/tested.xml','/root/received/tested.xml');`
 code returns file name that is `/root/received/tested.xml` on success else it will return undef
and for binary mode before `put` method add `$ftp_connection->binary();` 
hope below code will help you with your needs

```
use strict;
use Net::FTP;


my $ftp_connection=Net::Ftp->new('debian1.com');
$ftp_connection->login("myuser","password");
$ftp_connection->binary();

if($ftp_connection->put('D:/to_upload/tested.xml','/root/received/tested.xml')) {
    print "successful transfer"
} else {
    print "unsuccessful transfer"
}
$ftp_connection->quit;
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Please check for the `$ftp_connection->message`.
2. Write this statement before uploading the file to transfer in binary mode.

   $ftp_connection->binary